# .NET 6 - WPF CustomControl Template not applied though being in App Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

We are switching a huge WPF Appl. to .NET 6.0. At least one CustomControl which worked on 4.8 does not get it's template applied which is referenced via `Generic.xaml`. I am not sure if `Generic.xaml` is not loaded or something else needs to be considered.
The Style can be added manually to `Application.Resources.MergedDictionaries` via a simple "Add" call with the Source set to it. I can see the CustomControl Style afterwards with the Key being the correct Type. It is still not applied, as there is no visual representation and no call is made to the overriden `OnApplyTemplate` method.
If all else fails, can I apply a template manually if I have the given style, like just apply the Style manually to a newly created instance?

Also: the Projects are now SDK-Style, `AssemblyInfo.cs` was taken over and "generate assembly info" is set to false. It contains the standard `ThemeInfo` entry.

Just for clarification following the code which successfully finds the `Generic.xaml`. But before 6.0 `Generic.xaml` was loaded without doing anything.

```cs
    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary
    {
          Source = new Uri("/Contracts;component/Themes/Generic.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
    });
```

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Problem.

maybe u need to add the Assembly.cs at TopLevel of ur CustomControlLibrary

```
using System.Windows;
    
[assembly: ThemeInfo(
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, //where theme specific resource dictionaries are located
                                     //(used if a resource is not found in the page,
                                     // or application resource dictionaries)
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly //where the generic resource dictionary is located
                                          //(used if a resource is not found in the page,
                                          // app, or any theme specific resource dictionaries)
)]
```